# How to access the bot framework in my app?

Tags: azure, botframework

I have started to check the `LUIS` from yesterday. I am really confused to use it.

Now, I have successfully created the `LUIS` app and I also have published it to the `BOT framework`. And I can communicate with the BOT in `Azure -> BOT -> BOT Management -> Test in Web Chat`.

Now, I want to create my app and access to the BOT in the `Azure`. Is there any `SDK` to connect to the BOT?

I know the endpoint `"***endpoint/api/messages`". How can I process some authentication to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> want to create my app and access to the BOT in the Azure

If you’d like to embed your bot in web application, easiest way is using  with Web Chat channel to enable users to communicate with your bot in websites. For more information, please check:

- [Embed a bot in a website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-design-pattern-embed-web-site)
- [Microsoft Bot Framework Web
  Chat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

Besides, if your client app does not support web chat, you can also enable communication between your bot and your own client application by using the [Direct Line API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts).

> How can I process some authentication to use it?

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication) is about bot authentication, please refer to it.